# Android collapsable layout not working properly

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am using collapsable layout . Here is the main layout for that,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:id="@+id/main_content"
                                                 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                                                 tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bgheader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:background="@drawable/scenary"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                           xmlns:attrs="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                           xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                           android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                                           android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                           android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                                           android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                                           app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                                           app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/titleContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"

                android:gravity="center">
                <.utils.CustomFontTextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Toolbar Title"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    attrs:customFont="handyman_bold"
                    android:textSize="8pt"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"/>
            </FrameLayout>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_ToolBarRightBtn"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:tag="0"
                android:background="@null"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_shopping"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                />



        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/offwhite"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Inside the ViewPager I have a recycler view. Here is what I see when I load the app ,

[image]

When I scroll up the recycler view I am seeing this,

[image]

I am not sure why I see the gap initially and later it is getting filled with the app primary color. What a I doing here?

Attached animated gif  of my screen.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: There is no coordinatorlayout wrapping the appbarlayout in your post

Comment: Sorry updated question

Comment: @jayeshsolanki93 I have attached a screen flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One straightforward solution is to use design support library version 23.1.1 This issue happens for design support library 23.2.0 onwards.

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

Second solution is removing the line `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from the `CoordinatorLayout`.

**UPDATE :**

> in both case the toolbar is overlapping the image, so the portion under status bar is not visible

This is happening because `CollapsingToolbarLayout` class is a child of `FrameLayout`. So the views you pass in the framelayout will stack upon each other. that's why toolbar is overlapping the image. The simplest solution in your case I found is to put `android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` in the `ImageView`.

Comment: I tried the second option , but the status bar turns white when I remove the line, do you know why? Also in both case the toolbar is overlapping the image, so the portion under status bar is not visible, how to clear that?

Comment: Updated for the toolbar overlapping issue.

Comment: Thanks.Do you know why the status bar turned white?

Comment: Statusbar was truning white because `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` is required to move it to full screen. But adding this line is giving other issues. I think you should use 23.1.1 until you get some other better solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no  `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`in your FrameLayout

```
<FrameLayout
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:id="@+id/titleContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Comment: what if you surround with NestedScrollView as your Content layout